# No carga informaciòn en modal

Tags: javascript, laravel, blade

Estoy trabajando con laravel usando las plantillas blade y tratando de hacer que al seleccionar un registro en una tabla recolecte la informacion del id y pasarlo para que en un modal se muestre en forma de informe. Por lo que veo, el id se imprime en consola pero cuando se abre el modal no carga ninguna información. En el index tengo lo siguiente:

index.blade.php

```
@section('content')
    @include('Dashboard.Reportes.Correctivo.show')
    <div class="row" id="top">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                            @permission('crear.correctivo')
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success " data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#pre-create2"> Nuevo Reporte
                            </button>
                            @endpermission
                            @permission('firmar.correctivo')
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pre-firma2">
                                Firmar Reportes
                            </button>
                            @endpermission
                            @permission('menu.correctivos.pendientes')
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#pre-pendiente2">Correctivos Pendientes
                            </button>
                            @endpermission
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="padding:0px;">
                                <strong>Nota: </strong>Para filtrar la información solo escriba las palabras que desea
                                buscar separadas por espacios
                                Ejemplo: (hospital + nombre de biomédico)= Hospital local Juan Carlos
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <br>
    @if(Session::has('message2'))
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            {{Session::get('message2')}}
        </div>
    @endif
    <div id="msj-success" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display: none">
        <Strong> Permisos Actualizados</Strong>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="Reportes">
                    @if(count($Reportes)==0)
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <h3>No hay resultados de tu búsqueda ó no hay elementos para mostrar</h3>
                            <img src="../../Imagenes/nothinghere.png" class="img-responsive" style="margin: auto;"
                                 alt="">
                        </div>
                    @else
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed " id="prueba">

                                <thead class="titulos-tabla">
                                <th>Número Reporte</th>
                                <th>Empresa</th>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Realizado</th>
                                <th>Equipo</th>
                                <th>Marca</th>
                                <th>Modelo</th>
                                <th>Serie</th>
                                <th>Placa</th>
                                <th>Ubicación</th>
                                @level(3)
                                <th>Biomédico</th>
                                @endlevel
                                <th>Estado-Firma</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tfoot class="titulos-tabla">
                                <th>Número Reporte</th>
                                <th>Empresa</th>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>Realizado</th>
                                <th>Equipo</th>
                                <th>Marca</th>
                                <th>Modelo</th>
                                <th>Serie</th>
                                <th>Placa</th>
                                <th>Ubicación</th>
                                @level(3)
                                <th>Biomédico</th>
                                @endlevel
                                <th>Estado-Firma</th>
                                <th>Acciones</th>
                                </tfoot>
                                <tbody>
                                @foreach($Reportes as $Reporte)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            {{$Reporte->numeroReporte}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->equipo->clientes->nombreCliente}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->fecha}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->fechaRealizada}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->equipo->nombreEquipo}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->equipo->marcaEquipo}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->equipo->modeloEquipo}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->equipo->serieEquipo}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->equipo->placaEquipo}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->equipo->ubicacionEquipo}}</td>
                                        @level(3)
                                        <td>{{$Reporte->biomedico->nombreBiomedico}}</td>
                                        @endlevel
                                        <td>
                                            @if($Reporte->aprobacion_firma!="SI")
                                                {{"Pendiente"}}
                                            @else
                                                {{"Firmado"}}
                                            @endif
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @permission('mostrar.correctivo')
                                            <div class="col-sm-1" style="margin-right:10%">
                                                <button type="button" value="{{$Reporte->id}}"
                                                        onclick="MostrarReporte(this)"
                                                        class="btn btn-success fa fa-eye" data-toggle="modal"
                                                        data-target="#show"></button>
                                            </div>
                                            @endpermission
                                            @permission('editar.correctivo')
                                            <div class="col-sm-1">
                                                {!!link_to_route('Correctivo.edit', $title = '',
                                                 $parameters = $Reporte->id, $attributes =
                                                ['class'=>'btn btn-primary fa fa-pencil-square-o'])!!}
                                            </div>
                                            @endpermission
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

en mi js que es donde tengo el metodo donde le envio el id tengo lo siguiente:

```
function MostrarReporte(btn) {
    limpiarContenido();
    var ruta = "/Correctivo/" + btn.value;
    $.get(ruta, function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        //console.log(res.firma.url);
        $("#tittle-preventivo").text("Cliente: " + res.cliente.nombreCliente);
        $("#numeroReporte").text(res.reporte.numeroReporte);
        $("#fecha").text(res.reporte.fecha);
        $("#cliente").text(res.cliente.nombreCliente);
        $("#nombreEquipo").text(res.equipo.nombreEquipo);
        $("#serieEquipo").text(res.equipo.serieEquipo);
        $("#marcaEquipo").text(res.equipo.marcaEquipo);
        $("#modeloEquipo").text(res.equipo.modeloEquipo);
        $("#placaEquipo").text(res.equipo.placaEquipo);
        $("#ubicacionEquipo").text(res.equipo.ubicacionEquipo);
        $("#observaciones").html(res.reporte.observaciones.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));

        $("#firmaBiomedico").attr("src", "../" + res.biomedico.firma);
        $("#invima").text("Invima: " + res.biomedico.registroInvimaBiomedico);

        var anio = res.reporte.fecha.split("-")
        if(anio[0] <= 2016){
            $("#logo").append('<img id="logo" src="../../Imagenes/geomedicoslogo_antiguo.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">');
        } else{
            $("#logo").append('<img id="logo" src="../Imagenes/logoGeomedicosReporte.png" width="457px" height="100px">'); 
        }  
        
       if (res.firma != null) {
            $("#firmaUsuario").append('<img id="firmaUsuario" src="../' + res.firma.url + '" width="200" height="120">' +
                '<h5>Nombre: ' + res.firma.nombreUsuario + '</h5>');
        } else {
            $("#firmaUsuario").append('<h3>Pendiente por firma</h3>');
        }


        if (res.antes != null) {
            $(".page-break").append('<div class="col-xs-12 imagenesAntes "><div class="col-lg-12 text-center">' +
                '<h5>IMÁGENES ANTES DEL MANTENIMIENTO</h5>' +
                '</div></div>');
        }
        $.each(res.antes, function (key, value) {
            $(".imagenesAntes").append('<div class="col-xs-4"><div class="thumbnail"><a href="/' + value.url + '" ' +
                'data-lightbox="antes" data-title="Imágenes antes del mantenimiento"><img src="../' + value.url + '">' +
                '</a></div></div>');
        });
        if (res.despues != null) {
            $(".page-break").append('<div class="col-xs-12 imagenesDespues "><div class="col-lg-12 text-center">' +
                '<h5>IMÁGENES DESPUÉS DEL MANTENIMIENTO</h5>' +
                '</div></div>');
        }
        $.each(res.despues, function (key, value) {
            $(".imagenesDespues").append('<div class="col-xs-4"><div class="thumbnail"><a href="/' + value.url + '" ' +
                'data-lightbox="despues" data-title="Imágenes después del mantenimiento"><img src="../' + value.url + '">' +
                '</a></div></div>');
        });

    });
}
```

show.blade.php (modal)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" style="width:">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #5cb85c">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title text-center" id="tittle-preventivo">Modal title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                                                <thead>
                                                <th>
                                                    <td id="logo"></td>
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed"
                                                           style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>FI-004</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>VERSION 2</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>FECHA: 2016-03-28</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </th>
                                                </thead>
                                            </table>
                                            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                                                <thead>
                                                <th class="text-center" colspan="6">INFORMACIÓN DEL REPORTE</th>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Nº Reporte:</td>
                                                    <td id="numeroReporte"></td>
                                                    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">REPORTE DE MANTENIMIENTO TIPO
                                                        DE ACTIVIDAD:
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>CORRECTIVA</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Fecha de Reporte
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td colspan="4" id="fecha"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class="text-center" colspan="6">INFORMACIÓN DEL EQUIPO</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Empresa:</td>
                                                    <td colspan="6" id="cliente"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Nombre Equipo:</td>
                                                    <td id="nombreEquipo"></td>

                                                    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Serie Equipo:</td>
                                                    <td id="serieEquipo"></td>

                                                    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Marca Equipo:</td>
                                                    <td id="marcaEquipo"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Modelo Equipo:</td>
                                                    <td id="modeloEquipo"></td>

                                                    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Placa Equipo:</td>
                                                    <td id="placaEquipo"></td>

                                                    <td style="background-color:#EEEEEE;">Ubicación Equipo:</td>
                                                    <td id="ubicacionEquipo"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class="text-center">REPORTE</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td id="observaciones"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed"
                                                   style="margin-bottom:0px;width:100%">
                                                <tbody>
                                                <tr class="text-center">
                                                    <td colspan="3">
                                                        <h5>Biomédico:</h5>
                                                        <img id="firmaBiomedico" src="" width="200" height="120">
                                                        <h5 id="invima"></h5>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td colspan="3">
                                                        <h5>Funcionario:</h5>

                                                        <div id="firmaUsuario">
                                                            <h5 id="nombreUsuario"></h5>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <h5 id="nombreUsuario"></h5>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            <div class="page-break">


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer " style="background-color: #5cb85c">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Saben como puedo solucionarlo o que sugerencia me pueden brindar para corregir este caso?.

Comment: Podrías poner el código del modal? No lo veo ahí. Por otro lado, estás trabajando con Bootstrap? Qué versión? Porque no veo como se abre el modal.

Comment: @azeós adiciona el codigo faltante